# Finding each UART pin with multimeter

Tags: uart, multimeter, pins

I am trying to findout the pinout for Serial Connection to a router. However I wasn't able differentiate the pins other than GND.

Pinout:

```
PIN |  RESISTANCE (UNPLUGGED) | VOLTAGE (PLUGGED)

 1. ? -> 730ohm to the ground -> 3.35-3.37v
 2. GND
 3. ? -> Infinite resistance -> 3.34-3.36v
 4. ? -> Infinite resistance ->  3.32-3.34v
```

As far as I have read online. Rx should have been 0 (low). However all 3 pins are high. I don't know if this is a different interface or something is broken.

Edit: Added info about when this measurements taken.

---

### UPDATE:

I tracked the pins to the SoC and they going to a location where UART pins of SoC are. There are few more findings:

1. There was a sign around 1st pin which indicates Vcc pin, which I wasn't able to make sense before.
2. After checking pins for a longer time, I realized that 3rd pin
   fluctuates between 1.5-3.3v which indicates it's Tx. Therefore, that
   makes 4th pin Rx.

Alltogether, Jasen's answer is the correct one.

Comment: That's probably not going to work.  Also you must never use resistance mode on a powered circuit, as it involves injecting its own signal.

Comment: Whay are you expecting TX to be low?  idle is "mark", not space.

Comment: This seems to be a logic-level serial connection, not an RS232 that inverts the voltage. Did you try to inject "0" (GND) and "1" (VCC = 3.3V) **with a series resistor** of for example 1K? I'd expect no relevant changes on VCC and TX, and some kind of following on RX.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have tested resistance when its unplugged from the power source.

Comment: @Jasen I said Rx to be low not Tx.

Comment: @the-busybee no, i haven't inject ground or vcc. Could you explain it in an answer post please?

Comment: No, I will not, because it is not an answer. -- By testing with such a high-impedance source you can gain insight in the input impedance of the pins. TX should have a low impedance, RX a high one, VCC an even lower one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If forced to guess from the above:

- 1 as VCC.
- 3 as TX.
- 4 as RX.

Comment: could you please explain why?

Comment: Given the info, that really is the best guess. When VCC is on the connector, it will have the highest voltage, because other pins are connected possibly via chips and resistors. The second highest voltage is most likely TX because it is a low impedance output from the chip and driven high when idle. The lowest voltage is most likely RX because it is an input with only internal or external pull-up resistance, so it will be weakest signal pulled high.

Comment: Apperently your answer is correct. I tracked the pins to the SoC and they going to a location where UART pins of SoC available. Also there was a sign which indicates Vcc pin which I wasn't able to make sense before.